# Mac w/ Bootcamp + Win 10: unallocated space; 2nd Windows partition?

Tags: windows, mac, partitioning, ntfs, boot-camp

I've got a Mac Mini (Late 2012) with a 500GB HDD. Initially it was partitioned 50-50, half of it used by Mac OS, the other half was the Bootcamp partition (Windows 8.1. which I upgraded to 10).

I don't use Mac OS at all, so I just thought: let's shrink that partition and create a second NTFS partition to use with Windows instead. I went ahead, put GParted on a stick and took 180GB from the Mac partition.

That turned out to be a bad idea since Window wouldn't boot any more. I actually got that fixed using rEFIt. Took me several attempts though and honestly I'm not sure if I fully understand what I actually did.

So Windows boots again and everything's fine. Except now I have 180GB unallocated space and I don't dare formatting it because Disk Management says that by doing so I would convert the disk to dynamic which would prevent any other OS to load - I'm pretty sure If I kill Mac OS, Windows would be gone too.

So... what am I to do with that unallocated space? Would rEFIt be able to save the day again if I formatted that space, effectively allowing me to use two Windows partitions alongside Mac OS? Or would it just screw up everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware that rEFIt is abandonware. I forked [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) from it, and rEFInd is under active development. That said, it was almost certainly not rEFIt per se that fixed the problem, but `gptsync`, which is a program that ships with both rEFIt and rEFInd, but is more easily accessed from rEFIt. The purpose of `gptsync` is to create a [hybrid MBR,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) and that's really what you need to understand before you do anything else. I strongly recommend you read that link (which is to part of my documentation for `gdisk` -- a GPT disk partitioning tool that can also create and manipulate hybrid MBRs).

In brief, a hybrid MBR is a flaky and dangerous hack that Apple used to install Windows 7 and earlier. (Windows 8 and 10 may also boot in BIOS mode from a hybrid MBR, but fresh installations generally install in EFI mode to a pure GPT disk.) A hybrid MBR starts with a legal GPT disk but alters the data structures so that Windows treats it like an MBR disk that duplicates up to three GPT partitions, whereas OS X (and also Linux, FWIW) treats it as a GPT disk. Because the result is a disk with two independent partition tables, it's easy for these two partition tables to get out of sync -- all you need to do is to use a partitioning tool that understands one partitioning system but not the other, thus modifying one and leaving the other intact. In practice, the most dangerous tools for this are those that come with Windows, since they ignore the GPT side and modify the MBR side. (On a hybrid MBR disk, the GPT data structures really should take precedence when partitioning the disk, for various reasons.)

The GParted software you used modified the GPT data structures and then replaced the hybrid MBR with a legal protective MBR (part of the GPT data structures), thus turning the dangerous hybrid MBR into a legal GPT -- but this resulted in Windows being unable to boot. When you ran `gptsync`, it created a fresh hybrid MBR from the modified GPT data structures.

You can create new partitions or resize existing ones, but you should use GParted or some other GPT-aware tool for this job. You'll then need to create a fresh hybrid MBR. There are at least three ways to do this:

- **rEFIt's `gptsync`** -- Be aware that rEFIt's `gptsync` is rather limited. In particular, it adds Mac (and Linux, IIRC) partitions to the hybrid MBR, possibly squeezing out Windows partitions; but as OS X and Linux both use the GPT side, this approach can easily result in a useless hybrid MBR because the Windows partitions aren't included if they come after enough OS X and/or Linux partitions. If you resize your existing partitions, this is probably fine, since your current hybrid MBR seems to be working, so a new one created with the same algorithm will probably work, too; but if you create a new partition, it's conceivable that the new hybrid MBR will be missing one of the Windows partitions.
- **rEFInd's `gptsync`** -- The `gptsync` that comes with rEFInd is smarter in this respect, and will prioritize the inclusion of Windows partitions over OS X and Linux partitions. OTOH, rEFInd's emergency disks don't include `gptsync`, so you'll need to add it to the USB flash drive version or fully install rEFInd and configure it to enable use of `gptsync`. (I require such hoop-jumping because hybrid MBRs are flaky and dangerous, and I don't want people to create one accidentally.)
- **GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)** Another option is to use my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`),](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) which is by far the most flexible of these three programs at creating hybrid MBRs. This is likely to be most easily done from a Linux emergency disk, most of which come with `gdisk` installed. You'll need to have a better understanding of hybrid MBRs to be able to create one with `gdisk`, though. See the hybrid MBR documentation to which I've already linked.

Another option you might consider is to convert the Windows installation to boot in EFI mode rather than in BIOS mode. If you do this, you could convert the disk to a standard GPT disk without the hybrid MBR. Windows 8 and later normally boot fine in EFI mode on most Macs, but there may be some exceptions to this rule. Doing the conversion would involve switching the disk to using a legal GPT (adjusting the partition, as you need to do, with GParted, should do this) and then installing an EFI-mode Windows boot loader. I used to have links to pages describing how to do this, but they've all vanished recently, I'm afraid. The new Windows [MBR2GPT tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) can do it, but this tool does an MBR-to-GPT conversion, too. I don't know how it would react to a GPT disk with a hybrid MBR or to a pure GPT disk. Given the way other Windows tools handle hybrid MBR disks, you could end up losing your GPT partitions that are not duplicated in the hybrid MBR. All in all, although a conversion to an EFI-mode boot of Windows may be the best approach in the long term, the process of getting there is a bit uncertain at the moment and is likely to be riskier in the short term.

Speaking of risk, it's important that you back up your computer, or at least your important user data, before you do anything else. Even the least-risky options available to you carry some risk, and proceeding with these bleeding-edge operations carries a risk of serious data loss. If you lack adequate backup hardware, *buy it!* Even if you do nothing with your current setup, there's a risk of a software bug, malware, or hardware failure coming along and wiping out everything you've got.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed explanation! Very helpful indeed. :)

I think I'm gonna try my luck with rEFInd's gptsync after creating the new partition with GParted. Do I need to uninstall rEFIt first to be able to use rEFInd? Might removing rEFIt result into Windows not booting?

This Mac is used as a temporary arrangement for home since I moved my actual workstation into my new office. There was not much to lose (except time), hence the carelessness on my part.

Comment: rEFIt and rEFInd can coexist, but of course only one will come up as the default boot manager. (Which one can be adjusted by tools like `bless` in macOS, EasyUEFI in Windows [booted in EFI mode], or `efibootmgr` in Linux.) Alternatively, you could run rEFInd from a CD or USB flash drive, or copy rEFInd's `gptsync` over the equivalent program for rEFIt. (You might need to give it exactly the same name as rEFIt's `gptsync` -- rEFIt's filenames generally lack architecture codes, but rEFInd's filenames include them.) rEFInd should boot a BIOS-mode Windows just as rEFIt does.

Comment: ...so I've removed rEFIt and installed rEFInd on Mac OS. Where can I find the configuration file (any rEFInd file) to enable gptsync?
I've also tried the USB flash drive method but I honestly have no idea how to include gptsync to the image so it can actually be used. I have taken a long time reading through the documentations but couldn't find anything on that.

Also, in the Mac OS Startup Volume settings, there is nothing else but Mac OS available. No Windows, no rEFInd.

Is rEFInd supposed not to show up when pressing down Alt on startup? It only does if I don't.

Comment: in OS X, use `mountesp` (a script that comes with rEFInd) to mount the ESP. The script will report where the ESP is located (it's likely to be `/Volumes/ESP`). You can then go to the `EFI/refind` directory at that mount point (such as `/Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind` to edit the `refind.conf` file. You'll need to uncomment and edit the `showtools` line so that `gptsync` is among the options. You may also need to copy `gptsync_x64.efi` to the ESP's `EFI/tools` or root directory. (IIRC, `refind-install` copies the file on Macs, but doesn't make the `refind.conf` changes.)

Comment: Thanks again, rEFInd including gptsync is up and running. 
I didn't dare moving the partitions and resizing the Windows partition so I just created a new NTFS partition with GParted (would the former actually be more risky?).  However, on Windows, said partition is still just "unallocated space". Do I also need to flag it appropriately? Didn't find anything about "how to flag a second windows partition on a mac". ;)

Comment: I can't really comment further without seeing your partition tables. Try using `gdisk` for this: Type `p` in the main menu to show the GPT partitions, then `x` followed by `o` to show the MBR side. Edit your question to show everything, then add a comment here that you've done so.

Comment: I booted from a stick with SystemRescue (which should include gdisk) but could not find said tool. So I went ahead and actually moved+increased the Windows Partition. As expected, Windows does not boot any more ("No bootable device") but this time gptsync did not help. Any last idea?

Comment: ...actually, I've decided to wipe the whole disk, erasing everything and installing Windows 10 from scratch as the only OS. Don't want to mess with Mac OS and Bootcamp any more. Still, thank you very much for your help! I may not have succeded but I've certainly learned a lot. ;) I've donated a few bucks via paypal on your homepage, keep up the good work.